# zero read timeout for pcap

Tags: c, timeout, arguments, pcap

Is -1 a valid read timeout for pcap?

I was told by someone that setting to_ms to -1 in `pcap_open_live(char *device, int snaplen, int promisc, int to_ms, char *errbuf);` causes it to return immediately when a packet is detected - effectively a zero timeout. It makes a lot of sense that there be some way to set a zero timeout, but then why not make -1 be infinite and 0 be 0? That would be more logical. Additionally, I haven't been able in any way to confirm what effect a to_ms value of -1 has on pcap.

So, is -1 a valid timeout value? If so, what effect does it have? If not, is there any way to set a detection timeout of zero?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your explanation is making sense.

A timeout for a read call should only come in to play if *no data is ever present to be read*. In your case, if a packet is *never* received, then the timeout should control how long the call sits around waiting, before returning. If data is received, the timeout doesn't matter, since then the call must return as soon as it detects (and reads) the data, that's what's your asking it do do.

From [reading the code](https://github.com/mcr/libpcap/blob/master/pcap-linux.c), it seems a negative timeout in pcap means "non-blocking mode", which will make it *not wait at all*, but instead return directly if no data is available.

Comment: You misunderstand. The read timeout in this case applies where there _are_ packets to be read - to quote from the man page, `The read timeout is used to arrange that the read not necessarily return immediately when a packet is seen, but that it wait for some amount of time to allow more packets to arrive and to read multiple packets from the OS kernel in one operation`. So the read timeout causes it to delay returning after it detects a packet.